# "getvalue" function error "Sub or function not defined"

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to get the value using "getvalue" function in VBA.

```
Sub testgetvalue1()
Dim p As String
Dim t As String
Dim s As String
Dim a As String
p = "D:\Archive Mail"
t = "Excel_1"
s = "Sheet1"
a = "A1"
msgbox getvalue(p, t, s, a)
End Sub
```

It throws an error

> "Sub or function not defined"

and it highlights the "getvalue" function.

Comment: `getvalue` is not a native function. You are missing the part of the code where it is written as a User Defined Function (UDF).

Comment: Getvalue is not capitalised, so it is evident there is no such native function and you have to make one yourself

Answer (score 1):

`GetValue` is not a predefined function, so you need to define it yourself. Maybe you read an article that defined and used it. [Here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/) is such an article, that defines it as follows:

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Include this in your module, and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?